# Can I split a .net DLL without having to recompile other DLLs that reference the original one?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, runtime, late-binding

I have a C# project that builds into a single DLL with two classes, ClassA and ClassB. For project management reasons, I'd like to move ClassB into a separate DLL, leaving the original DLL with ClassA only.

The problem is that I have other DLLs (also compiled from C#) that reference ClassA and ClassB in their original DLL. ClassA is fine but calling ClassB ends up with a TypeLoadException.

(I *could* recompile all of those other DLLs with their new project references, but I'd rather not do that, again for project management reasons.)

Is there a way I could deploy my new split DLLs and have the other DLLs continue to work? Or, do I really need to bite the proverbial bullet and plan to deploy new versions of all these files?

Comment: Followup question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47654493/3568

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You achieve this using *Type forwarding*. This enables moving a type to another assembly. In the original assembly, you add a `TypeForwardedTo`-attribute to signal that the type has been moved.

See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/type-forwarding-in-the-common-language-runtime) for detailed information.

Comment: Would it be recommended to leave a note in documentation that the according part has been moved and in new projects the new assembly should be referenced directly? I am thinking that one wouldn't want this to be in the code forever ...

Comment: @Fildor Yes, I'd add this to documentation for the team and use the new location directly if I'd add or change code that uses the class.